# Get the current region of user on watchkit 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, watchkit

I am working on a app on watch app. The app version is watch 2.0 and i'm using the xcode 7.3.1. and the swift version is 2 which i have used in my code.

Now the problem is i want to show an alert according to the current language that is selected in the user's watch. But i'm not able to get the current language of watch. It always return the en_us. I have checked the many post's but no one solution worked for me.

So now i have decided to show the alert according to the region of user. I have check the code on iphone its working properly but i dont know that if watchkit is able to detect the current region of user.The code that i have used to check the current region is :

```
 let countryCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String
        print("countryCode\(countryCode)")
```

If anyone have any idea about it then please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use Xcode 9, Swift 4 and WatchOS 4?

Comment: Thanks for replay. Actually i'm working on a  project and the client of the project don't want to update the code of working mobile app.So i need to add the new functionality in same version.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `let userLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages.first` to get the language currently used by the user. This API is available from `watchOS2`, so that should be fine, but I couldn't test Swift 2, so the property names might be slightly different.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer but i already try it. It always return the same language on simulator (e.g en_US). And the another problem is the watch simulator don't have any option to change the device language. So there is no way test the watch app.

Comment: You should be testing on a real device rather than the Simulator. Moreover, as far as I know, the Watch uses the same language settings as your phone so changing the language on the phone should change the language of the watch as well.

Comment: So it means if i set the mobile language to chinese the watch language will replaced with the selected one ?? is this is possible on real device or on simulator also??

Comment: Actually i  read about it from an another post and try it but it don't works for me on simulator.

Comment: You should always do testing of Settings/hardware related code on real devices instead of the Simulator. This is especially true for testing the Watch with data coming from the iPhone. And yes, if you change your phone's language to Chinese, the language of the connected Watch should change accordingly.

Comment: Okkk.. a big thanks for your help. I will try to test it on real device.